# Why does using case_when give me an error when trying to mutate into a new variable?

Tags: r

I am trying to mutate a set of variables to add new variables with changed values below:

```
ELSE <- TRUE

Engagement_Master <- Engagement_Master %>%
  mutate(`My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment%` = case_when( `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment` == "Strongly agree" ~ "1",
                                                                      `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment` == "Agree" ~ "1",
                                                                      `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment` == "Neither agree nor disagree" ~ "0",
                                                                      `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment` == "Disgree" ~ "0",
                                                                      `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment` == "Strongly disagree" ~ "0",
                                                                      ELSE ~ NA))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `My work gives me a sense of personal accomplishment% = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
```

I was expecting it to work because I have previously used this expression without error.

Comment: You can omit the final `ELSE ~ NA`, since unmatched cases will be `NA` by default. But the correct syntax would be `TRUE ~ NA`.

Comment: Always worth checking the function documentation; `?case_when`

Comment: Sometime you also have to specify what kind of NA such as NA_numeric etc